# tensorflow stopped and no error report

Tags: python, tensorflow

my python version is 3.6.5

CUDA version is 9.0

tensorflow version is 1.9.0

I'm a beginner. I build a CNN network and run it in python shell. But it doesn't work, and no error report, so I don't know what the problem is. Later, the python shell restart.

Here is my code, hope somebody can help me. Thanks a lot!

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
#ms=readmnist.mnistset()

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)
#parameters 
learning_rate = 0.01
num_steps = 200
batch_size = 16
display_step = 10
tf.reset_default_graph()

x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,784])
y_=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,10])
#def of objects
class NN:
    def __init__(self):
        self.W={}
        self.b={}
        self.layer={}
        self.n=0
    def creatNN(self,x,inputsize,outputsize):
        self.W[self.n]=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([inputsize,outputsize],mean=0.0,stddev=0.2))
        self.b[self.n]=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([outputsize],mean=0.0,stddev=0.2))
        self.layer[self.n] =tf.add(tf.matmul(x,self.W[self.n]),self.b[self.n])
        self.n=self.n+1
        return self.layer[self.n-1]

class CNN:
    def __init__(self):
        self.wc={}
        self.bc={}
        self.layer={}
        self.clayer={}
        self.n=0
    def creatCNN(self,x,strides=1,k=2,coresize=5,tsize=1,outputsize=32):
        self.wc[self.n]=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([coresize,coresize,tsize,outputsize]))
        self.bc[self.n]=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([outputsize]))
        self.layer[self.n]=tf.nn.conv2d(x, self.wc[self.n], strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME')
        self.layer[self.n]=tf.nn.bias_add(self.layer[self.n],self.bc[self.n])
        self.layer[self.n]=tf.nn.relu(self.layer[self.n])
        self.clayer[self.n]=tf.nn.max_pool(self.layer[self.n],ksize=[1,k,k,1],strides=[1,k,k,1],padding='SAME')
        self.n=self.n+1
        return self.clayer[self.n-1]

x_img = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])
'''
construct the network 
'''
nn=NN()
cnn=CNN()
cnn1=cnn.creatCNN(x_img,1,2,5,1,32)
cnn2=cnn.creatCNN(cnn1,1,2,5,32,64)
tnn=tf.reshape(cnn2,[-1,7*7*64])
nn1=nn.creatNN(tnn,7*7*64,1024)
nn1=tf.nn.relu(nn1)
output=nn.creatNN(nn1,1024,10)
y=tf.nn.softmax(output)
y=tf.clip_by_value(y, 1e-20, 1)

#train 
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_ *tf.log(y))
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
loss=cross_entropy
train_step = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
#start 
for traintime in range(1000):
    #trainlab_nextbatch, trainimg_nextbatch =  ms.train_nextbatch(batch_size)
    trainimg_nextbatch, trainlab_nextbatch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x:trainimg_nextbatch, y_ :trainlab_nextbatch})

    if traintime %200 == 0:
        print(sess.run(loss,feed_dict={x:trainimg_nextbatch, y_ :trainlab_nextbatch}))
        print(sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x:trainimg_nextbatch, y_ :trainlab_nextbatch}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finished this question myself.

I run this code in powershell, not python shell, and I get the result , it means I don't have cudnn. And it remind me that I only set cudnn for cuda 9.2， not for 9.0， so I set up cudnn again and solve this problem.

Though problem solved, my CNN still work no good, it will take my more time to upgrade my CNN.